# Using bash to add an xml tag to specific location

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

Hi I've been looking around for a while and haven't found a viable solution. I am new to bash so apologies!

I am trying to add an xml function tag `<generalSideMenu />` to a specific position in an xml file underneath <null>.

I also want to run this script from a text file that I am running line by line from the controller.

Hope that all makes sense and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Parsing xml with base/sed/awk whatever is a definitely bad idea. Use proper parser libraries from Ruby/Python whatever you want to

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML handling tool. For example, in [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), you can just type

```
open file.xml ;
xinsert element generalSideMenu into //null ;
save :b ;
```